# R. Same command gives different plots. Variable vs. Character string

Tags: r, plot, user-defined-functions

I lied. They aren't quite the same commands. But I don't see how they are different.

I made a function sales.deriv. It's definition is at the bottom of the page. The function finds the derivative of sales data from the given dataframe and plots it. (They're are probably plenty of inefficiencies in how I coded it. Feel free to comment on them but cleaning them up is not my focus here.)

Command One,

```
> sales.deriv(trans.df=subset(trans, Week < 27  & Week > 8 & Day == "Wednesday"))
```

returns Plot One:

[image: Plot 1]

Command Two,

```
> Day <- "Wednesday"
> sales.deriv(trans.df=subset(trans, Week < 27  & Week > 8 & Day == Day))
```

returns Plot Two:

[image: Plot 2]

As you can see, the plots are different — most noticeably in the number of relative peaks before 11. By defining `Day <- "Wednesday"`, though, it seems to me the commands should be identical. What's going on here?

Function definition:

```
sales.deriv <- function(trans.df, plot=TRUE, xmin=7, xmax=18, ymin=0, ymax=150, title = "Rate of Revenue", pch=1, col="black", n=50, cex=1)
{
trans$Net.Sales[is.na(trans$Net.Sales)] <- 0
trans.time <- trans.df[order(trans.df$Time.Dec),]
fake.bins <- ddply(trans.df[c("Date","Net.Sales")], .(Date), summarize, Net.Sales = sum(Net.Sales))
trans.time$Cum.Sum <- cumsum(trans.time$Net.Sales) / nrow(fake.bins)
time.fit2 <- lm(Cum.Sum ~ poly(Time.Dec, n, raw=T), data=subset(trans.time, Hour >= 6 | Time.Dec<20))
sales.rate <- data.frame(Time.Dec=seq(from=xmin, to=xmax, by=.0333))
sales.rate$Cum.Sum <- predict(time.fit2, sales.rate)
dYdX <- diff(sales.rate$Cum.Sum)/diff(sales.rate$Time.Dec)
sales.rate$dYdX <- c(0,dYdX)
if (!plot) {
points(dYdX~Time.Dec, data=sales.rate, col=col, xlim=c(xmin,xmax), ylim=c(ymin,ymax), main=title, cex=cex, pch=pch) 
} else {
plot(dYdX~Time.Dec, data=sales.rate, col=col, xlim=c(xmin,xmax), ylim=c(ymin,ymax), main=title, pch=pch, cex=cex, xlab="Time", ylab="Revenue per Hour", xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=seq(from=xmin, to=xmax, by=1))}}
```

Comment: don't use subset and you won't run into this problem. you should also use the space bar while writing code especially if you share it

Comment: @rawr Will do with the spaces. How do I go about without subset? I had been using matrices/multiplication before (`df[df[,"Week"]>30,]`) but switched to subset when I had multiple conditions.

Comment: well for the first one, you could use `sales.deriv(df=trans[with(trans, Week < 27  & Week > 8 & Day == "Wednesday"), ]` test this example with how you're trying to use subset `subset(mtcars, mpg > 30); x <- 'mpg'; subset(mtcars, x > 30)`

Comment: oh cool. i didn't know i could do that. any reason i should ever use subset?

Comment: okay. i made the change, both in the function and in the command, but to no result. still the different plots.

Comment: I just found that in defining `sales.rate` I used a | where I should have used an &. Changed it

Comment: forgot to mention you again, @rawr. thanks for all your help.

Comment: In your second example you define `Day <- "Wednesday"`. As a consequence, the logical operation `Day == "Wednesday"` will *always* return `TRUE` in the subsequent command and can therefore as well be omitted, like in `sales.deriv(df=subset(trans, Week < 27  & Week > 8)`. This is why you obtain different plots.

Comment: In your calls you are passing a named argument called `df`, but the function expects an argument `trans.df`.